# How to use zend-form-decorators-bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework2

I'm trying to integrate my ZF2 project Forms with [Twitter Bootstrap 3.0.2](http://getbootstrap.com/). In order to achieve  this, I downloaded Emagister's [zend-form-decorators](https://github.com/Emagister/zend-form-decorators-bootstrap/tree/bootstrap3). So, what now? How can I use the sources? I can't find where should I copy `Twitter` folder (It's not a module) and how to render forms. My project is based on ZF2 skeleton project.

Comment: You must be joking. This project uses zf1. zf2 don't uses decorators.

Comment: Bad news for me. After all, is there a way to render a zf2 form in bootstrap way?

Comment: one of the ways - ZF2 modules. But for myself, I do not use it. Use http://modules.zendframework.com (use search).